# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException with VSTO and call to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_HTMLBody()

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, mailitem

I am getting the following COM Exception when calling the MailItem.get_HTMLBody() method of the Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 (VSTO) Library.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
>   (0xF7A04001): Not Implemented.   with
>   Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._MailItem.get_HTMLBody()

Unlike previous known causes of this issue ([MailItem.HtmlBody throws a Not Implemented exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35853432/mailitem-htmlbody-throws-a-not-implemented-exception)), the code in question is not running on a separate thread.

The Environment is pretty unique. It is a Terminal Server (MS Server 2012) with up to 60 concurrent users, but only one user has this recurring error. For the other 60 users the code runs fine.

The only explanation I can think of is that there are some Visual Studio Tools for Office 2010 keys corrupt in his local registry overriding the "All Users" installation of the VSTO tools.

Comment: You are not getting this error from VSTO - it comes from the Outlook Object Model. Does this happen fro all items? Or just some? You might ant to post the relevant snippet of your code.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, thanks for answering. I asked the customer a few days ago to see if this happened with other areas of our Add-In when using the MailItem.HTMLBody property, he has not answered. The Code in question runs during the ribbon initialisation code, in this case we (due to the fact that Email Headers can be stripped off) are looking for certain html tags in the email to see if our Add-In Download button should be enabled.

Comment: When exactly does this call occur? You might want ti post the relevat snippets of your code.